# How to interpret internal_ram data section in NXP

Tags: microcontroller, memory, nxp, linker

In .lcf (linker configuration file) in my project, in SRAM memory there is an `internal_ram` section:

[image]

And in my case this `internal_ram` section is overlapping .bss, heap, and stack sections after compilation.

Because of that, I wonder what is being stored there if stack and heap variables have their own sections?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because wrong stack exchange

Comment: @DavideAndrea well, I also didn't know to which stack exchange go with this question, but it seems like it's more like an issue between hardware and software...

Comment: yeuop: It's 100% software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the linker script you have posted, internal_ram does not overlap into heap nor stack.

If the compiled program does, that means that you have filled the RAM with static allocations and that you are now overwriting the heap and stack areas. Doing so will cause data corruption and eventually program malfunction.

Some compilers warns about this, but not all.

You must use less RAM (maybe you can change some memory allocations to const, i.e. move to flash?), or change the size of heap/stack in order to avoid this. Or use a device with more RAM.

Comment: Thank you sir, it explains MCU strange behaviour. I will try to optimize it